# DOM querySelectorAll Manipulation Multiple Classes

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, dom-manipulation

I've been trying to do show and hide password feature on my project but still having issues with DOM Manipulation multiple classes, the idea is that when I click the eye icon then the input type change from password to text, here's my codes

index.html

```
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="far fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="text" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="OLD PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle"></i>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="far fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="text" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="NEW PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle"></i>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="far fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="text" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle"></i>
</div>
```

app.js

```
const eyeIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.passwordToggle');
const passwordForms = document.querySelectorAll('.passwordForms');

function test(){
    <!-- I'm not sure with 'this' -->
    const type = this.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    this.setAttribute('type', type);


    this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
}

for (let i = 0; i < eyeIcon.length; i++){
    eyeIcon[i].addEventListener('click',test)
}
```

I've been able to toggle the eye icon, but not the input type, what should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` will belong to the element on which the event handler is attached.

In your case that will be the `i` icon. You want to get its sibling's child.

```
this.parentNode// parent Node
this.parentNode.querySelector('input') //first input element in the parent
```

Use this inside your test function

```
    const type = this.parentNode.querySelector('input').getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    this.parentNode.querySelector('input').type = type;
```

Comment: where should I put those? I'm bit confused @Tushar

Comment: Your two lines at top of test function. This code does the same thing as you did but this time the correct element is selected.

Comment: Nice. Please accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
// Select all 'eye' icons and, for each of them...
document.querySelectorAll('.passwordToggle').forEach(item => {
    // ... add an event listener for the 'click' event, which...
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // ... selects the corresponding input element...
    const inputElement = item.parentElement.querySelector('.password > input');
    // ... and toggle its type
    inputElement.type = inputElement.type === 'text' ? 'password' : 'text';
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="text" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="OLD PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle"></i>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="text" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="NEW PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle"></i>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="text" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle"></i>
</div>

<!-- The following line is not necessary, I am including it only to display the icons in the snippet -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4e29af29a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[EDIT] You can toggle the 'eye' icon too, if you want:

```js
function toggleEyeIcon(iconElement) {
  iconElement.classList.toggle('fa-eye');
  iconElement.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
}

function toggleInputType(inputElement) {
  if (inputElement.type === 'text') {
    inputElement.type = 'password';
  } else {
    inputElement.type = 'text';
  }
}

// Select all 'eye' icons and, for each of them...
document.querySelectorAll('.passwordToggle').forEach(item => {
    // ... add an event listener for the 'click' event, which...
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // ... selects the corresponding input element...
    const inputElement = item.parentElement.querySelector('.password > input');
    // ... toggle its type...
    toggleInputType(inputElement);
    // ... and toggle the 'eye' icon CSS class
    toggleEyeIcon(item);
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="OLD PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle"></i>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="NEW PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle"></i>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle"></i>
</div>

<!-- The following line is not necessary, I am including it only to display the icons in the snippet -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4e29af29a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that *this* is the element that the listener is attached to, not the input element you want to change the type of. You can get to the input by going from the "eye" element to the closest ancestor div, then going down to the first input or element with class ".passwordForms", e.g.

```js
function toggleType(evt) {
  // Up to ancestor div
  let el = this.closest('div');
  // Down to .passwordForms element
  let inp = el.closest('div').querySelector('.passwordForms');
  // Toggle type
  inp.setAttribute('type', inp.getAttribute('type') == 'text'? 'password' : 'text');
}

// Attach listeners
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.passwordToggle').forEach(el =>
    el.addEventListener('click', toggleType)
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="far fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="text" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="OLD PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle">eye</i>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="far fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="text" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="NEW PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle">eye</i>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <div class="password">
        <i class="far fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="text" class = "passwordForms" name="" value="" placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD">
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-eye passwordToggle">eye</i>
</div>
```